# Filesystems, and quota for the home directory and /usr/local on the Google Cloud VM

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, linux-disk-free

I created a Debian VM on google cloud. Below is information from "df -h". What are those filesystems, such as tmpfs or /dev/sda1, mean? Any beginner-friendly reference for them? In particular, how much space can I use at my working directory "~", and how much space can I use in /usr/local (for installing software). Any idea?

```
zell@instance-1:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           371M  6.4M  365M   2% /run
/dev/sda1       9.8G  1.4G  7.9G  15% /
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df -h
```

shows the [amount of disk space used and available on Linux file systems](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/df.1.html). The command `df` stands for Disk Free and `-h` means human-readable form.

You can also see information about a specific filesystem, as follows:

```
df /dev/sda1
```

---

From [Documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/tmpfs.txt):

> **Tmpfs is a file system which keeps all files in virtual memory. 
>   Everything in tmpfs is temporary in the sense that no files will be
>   created on your hard drive. If you unmount a tmpfs instance,
>   everything stored therein is lost.**

They can be mounted on different directories. For example, a `tmpfs` filesystem mounted at `/dev/shm` is used for the implementation of POSIX shared memory, an inter-process communication (IPC) where two or more processes may read from and write to the shared memory region, and POSIX semaphores, which allows processes and threads to sync their actions.

---

From [What does /dev/sda mean?](https://superuser.com/questions/558156/what-does-dev-sda-for-linux-mean):

> `/dev/` is the part in the unix directory tree that contains all "device" files -- unix traditionally treats just about everything you can access as a file to read from or write to. Therefore, `/dev/sda1` means the first partition on the first drive, and `/dev/sda9` will mean the ninth partition on the first drive.

Check out the link for more information.

---

**To [display the amount of disk space used](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/du.1.html) by the specified files and for each subdirectory, you can run the following command:**

```
du -h
```

WHERE `du` stands for Disk Usage and `-h` means human-readable form.

Optionally you can use the following command to display the amount of disk space used by a certain directory:

```
du -h usr/local
```